# How to spoof source address when using snmptrap to use a different IP other than localhost

Tags: snmp, mib, network-monitoring, snmp-trap

I am using following snmptrap command to generate v2 traps. This generates a trap and it's received on Manager. However, the received trap has source address as sender's machine IP address. My requirement is to send the trap with someother IP

'''
snmptrap -v 2c -c abcd 1.1.1.1 '' '.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4' .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4 s "Interface-name" ifAdminStatus i 1 ifOperStatus i 1
'''

Can someone please guide me how to do modify the source IP in snmptrap command for v2?